# How can I show the difference on click of the file path in gerrit ui?

Tags: gerrit

I am having `project.xml` in `abc.zip`. I need to show the difference of `project.xml` which is inside the zip file. Gerrit ui contains `/c/abc/xyz/abc.zip`. How can I show the difference on click of the file path in gerrit ui? Also expecting in which file under gerrit source I need to do changes?

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit doesn't know about zip files; the only way you can see the difference is to download both versions, manually unzip them, and do a local diff.

Comment: I agree it can't read zip files. But How can I customize the UI to show the diff of the zip? I have the extraction of zip logic in java

Comment: The UI can't be customized in this way.  The diff is done on the server side and only rendered in the UI.